# The nord color scheme for vim does not match the documentation

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I installed the scheme according to the instructions, but the colors are still not as in the documentation.
https://github.com/arcticicestudio/nord-vim
OS - ubuntu 14, connecting via ssh.
Applied, restarted vim.

```
:PlugInstall
~$ vim ~/.vimrc
Error detected while processing /home/test/.vimrc:
line   17:
E518: Unknown option: termguicolors
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

[image]

Comment: In general, problems with a plugin should be discussed in its issue tracker. In this case, your Vim doesn't have the desired option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved problem.**

Indeed, the problem was the lack of termguicolors.
Ubuntu was vim running version 7.4..
termguicolors has been added to vim since version 8. I had to update vim.
Thank you all.

```
vim --version
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vim
vim --version
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Glad it worked out - maybe you could accept/upvote my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like you don't have that feature compiled on your
version of vim. Although it's not clear to me if you have `set termguicolors`
in your .vimrc because it was part of the installation instructions or not.
Either way, from `:help: termguicolors`:

```
                    'termguicolors' 'tgc' E954
'termguicolors' 'tgc'   boolean (default off)
            global
            {not available when compiled without the
            +termguicolors feature}
```

You can check if you have the 'termguicolors' feature by doing:

```
:version
```

and seeing if the 'termguicolors' has a '+' in front of it (you have it) or a
'-' in front of it (you don't).

Comment: Thanks for - 'vim --version'.

Answer (score 0):

The error is fairly self-explanatory: you are setting an option that is not available in your Vim.

You have a few ways to get out of this situation…

- Not setting the `:help 'termguicolors'` option at all.
- Setting it conditionally:

  ```
  if exists('+termguicolors')
      set termguicolors
  endif
  ```

  See `:help exists()`.
- Installing a Vim build that includes the `termguicolors` feature (and making sure your terminal emulator supports it).

Note that this colorscheme's promised look can only be achieved in:

- GUI Vim,
- TUI Vim with the `termguicolors` feature built-in and the `termguicolors` option set, in a suitable terminal emulator,
- in TUI Vim, if you [change the colour palette](https://www.nordtheme.com/) of your terminal emulator.

You should have read [the instructions](https://www.nordtheme.com/docs/ports/vim/installation) before installing that plugin.